# In typescript, same but mutually exclusive types?

Tags: typescript

I want to define string type that has distinct feature.
For example, like below.

```
type CapitalizedString = Capitalize<string>;
```

and I want to distinguish between this type and string type.

```
type CapitalizedString = Capitalize<string>;

const capitalizedString: CapitalizedString = 'Hello';
const anyString = 'world';

function print(text: CapitalizedString) {
    console.log(text);
}

print(capitalizedString);
print(anyString as CapitalizedString);
print('foo' as CapitalizedString);

print(anyString); // wants to occur error
print('foo'); // wants to occur error
```

Is there any way to make it be possible?

Comment: What is Capitalize<string> in type? If you change type to something like
   type CapitalizedString = { CapString :  string} 
will give error on print(anyString); though it will continue the execution

Comment: This will work for string literal types, but not for `string` .. you might also use branded types to mark strings that are checked to be capitalized. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghmAlsOAbRAvCATAysAJ0QDsBzKAXlgWTUwgB4BnQk0gPgG4BYAKD4DGAe2IsoAminRY8rMgC5qSKfVlEylKAHIAEhFSohWnr2GjgUOMRD515KloDuQgqmzG+fAGYBXYgOBEESgwdWAGABUoCAAPYAhibCYoFjt2AAp4uMUogDIoJVppRgj2AEooAG8+AoKzJiFUCAA6Q1JM2OAykwBfT15QkmB0iWU6GVs2br5B4mGrGzlyOGT4MeK1KZNZ4a0vISNLVclxnEmyaf4BsPSF89JuqAB6J6hHK2Bk4CEoIQEBHwEaIEAguGY3PYHLSPF5vD5fH5-AFAiAglxAA